# Optimize SQL query return individual

Tags: sql, wordpress

currently I do 2 separate sql queries since each one delivers the results indicated.
My question is how to get these results in only 1 query since both are in the wp_postmeta table

```json
$data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE '_stock_status' AND `meta_value` LIKE 'instock' ORDER BY `post_id`  DESC" );
$data1 = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE '_wc_pre_orders_enabled' ORDER BY `post_id`  DESC" );
```

Note: I must indicate that it can be grouped by the post_id
Thanks

**Updated
I made the query so that the values are grouped in 1 but the problem is that since the keys have the same value.
The values of query 1 are lost by joining the values of query 2.**

```json
$data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE '_stock_status' AND `meta_value` LIKE 'instock' OR `meta_key` LIKE '_wc_pre_orders_enabled' AND `meta_value` LIKE 'yes' GROUP BY  `post_id` ORDER BY `post_id`  DESC" );
```

Can something be done so that the values of query 1 remain and are not overwritten?

Comment: You can use OR to merge those all conditions in 2 queries.Or using UNION

Comment: ```json
0 => {#11023 ▼
    +"meta_id": "155032"
    +"post_id": "19433"
    +"meta_key": "_stock_status"
    +"meta_value": "instock"
  }
  1 => {#11027 ▼
    +"meta_id": "155054"
    +"post_id": "19433"
    +"meta_key": "_wc_pre_orders_enabled"
    +"meta_value": "yes"
  }
```

Comment: If I do that I get results separately and not within the same array :(

Comment: I meant sth like this:
$data = $wpdb->get_results(
 "SELECT 1, * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE '_stock_status' AND `meta_value` LIKE 'instock' 
 UNION
 SELECT 2, * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE '_wc_pre_orders_enabled'");

Comment: It doesn't work because meta_key and meta_value replace the content of the first query.

Can I save it as meta_key2 and meta_value2 in the generated array for the second query?

Comment: the same thing happens if I do it with "group by post_id" the only way would be to save the result of the first query in the array in different fields.

Comment: That's why I added 1 and 2 before * to identify where the data from. If you OR, you can case when the logic:

$data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT *, case when (`meta_key` LIKE '_stock_status' AND `meta_value` LIKE 'instock') then 1 else 2 end temp_col  FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE (`meta_key` LIKE '_stock_status' AND `meta_value` LIKE 'instock') OR (`meta_key` LIKE '_wc_pre_orders_enabled' AND `meta_value` LIKE 'yes') GROUP BY  `post_id` ORDER BY `post_id`  DESC" );

Then you can identify by 1 and 2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244970/discussion-between-hana-and-club).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I merge two MySQL queries into one?](//stackoverflow.com/q/584571/90527)